# With a SCORM 2004 LMS and/or SCORM 2004 SCO's, can a teacher change the sequencing?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I've been skimming over the numerous documents that describe SCORM 2004 and believe that the sequencing of activities is specified in the metadata of each SCO.  So, an SCO can define which other SCOs should be presented in case of passing or failing particular objectives that it presented.   Assuming that I'm correct, this suggests that the sequencing is rather static.

Our current LMS, which is not SCORM compliant also prescribes which activities a student should view if they pass or fail particular objectives.  It also allows a teacher to override prescriptions.

Does SCORM 2004 enable this sort of sequencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the sequencing of activities is specified in the metadata of each SCO

No. The sequencing of activities is implemented through `<sequencing>` element in manifest file.

> the sequencing is rather static

In SCORM 2004, the sequencing is completely dynamic; the sequencing implementation identifies the next activity based on both Tracking Model and Sequencing Definition Model of activities. In fact, the values of Tracking Model are dynamic but the values of Sequencing Definition Model are static. Actually, in SCORM 2004, the sequencing implementation collects the result of learner interactions with SCO (through CMI data model) and maps them to the Tracking Model and then evaluates the sequencing rules (defined for activities) based on the Tracking Model.